# How to use case statement in group by category in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, case

I have a following table

```
Id   Values    
 1     A          
 1     A          
 1     B          
 2     @          
 2     @
 2     @
 3     A
 3     A
 3     A
 3     A
 3     @
 4     B
 4     B
 4     B
```

Output:

```
Id   Values
 1     @
 2     @
 3     A
 4     B
```

Within each `Id` group, if all values are `@`, I want to set the value for that `Id` to `@`
else if all values for `Id` are same (ignoring `@`s) (e.g. all `A`s), set the value for that `Id` to be that value (`A`) else set value of id to `@`.

How do I run that `CASE` statement to give one unique value to each `Id` in `SQL Server`?

New to `SQL Server`, please help.

Comment: have you tried `GROUP BY Id, Values` ?

Answer (score 1):

use `GROUP BY` on `ID` and check for `MIN ()` and `MAX ()`. If min = max means, all value are the same.

For you case the twist is the `@`. It should be ignore. The trick is to use `NULLIF()` on `@`

```
select  id,
        case    when    min(NULLIF([Values], '@')) = max(NULLIF([Values], '@'))
                and     min(NULLIF([Values], '@')) <> '@'
                then    min(NULLIF([Values], '@'))
                else    '@'
                end
from    yourtable
group by id
```